# Is it possible to scale time in Spritekit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create game that speedup every seconds. If I want to achieve something like this in Unity, I will just scale Time.timeScale param. Is there something like this in SpriteKit? Or should I just set diffrent speed and spawn params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the `speed` variable on your scene and physics world

E.G. To make your game twice as fast

```
let scaledTime : CGFloat = 2

scene.speed = scaledTime
scene.physicsWorld.speed = scaledTime
```

Comment: sure, like anything thing else that gets abused.  But for basic use, no, it is designed to work in Sprite kit